# Prove that both the range and null space of E are invariant under T if and only it ET=TE.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

**Exercise** Let $E$ be a projection on $V$ and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. 1) Prove that the range of $E$ is invariant under $T$ if and only if $ETE=TE$. 2) Prove that both the range and null space of $E$ are invariant under $T$ if and only if $ET=TE$.

**1)**
Note that any projection $E$ is represented by a matrix that is "part of" an identity matrix. For simplicity's sake, let us consider the basis $B=\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r,...,\alpha_n\}$ such that $E_{ii}=1$ for $i\leq r$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Let $\alpha=(a_1,...,a_n)$, then $T(E(\alpha))=T(a_1,...,a_r,...,0)=\beta$. If we assume $T$ to be invariant over the range $W$ of $E$, then $\beta\in W$. $$\beta=(\beta_1,...,\beta_r,...,0),\qquad E\beta=\beta$$
Therefore $ETE=TE$. If we assume to the contrary that $ETE\neq TE$, then $TE\notin W$ so $T$ is not invariant over $W$.

*After some struggling this seemed to go pretty well. Though the last argument makes me think that there may be a much faster way to prove this. Part 2 is where I've been bumping my head against a wall though.*

**2)** Consider the same basis $B$ and let $TE\neq ET$. Then there exists some $\alpha\in V$ such that $T(a_1,...,a_r,...,0)\neq(Ta_1,...,Ta_r,...,0)$, but if this is the case, $T$ is not invariant to $W$. Assuming that $T$ is invariant to $W, \quad T(a_1, ..., a_r,...,0)\in W$ for all $\alpha\in W$. Therefore $$T(a_1, ..., a_r,...,0)=(Ta_1, ..., Ta_r,...,0)$$
And $TE=ET$.

*The way I've been treating the transformation (just pulling it inside the vector), is that something that is allowed? I've been able to convince myself but wouldn't be able to defend it to someone else.*

Comment: So your vector space $V$ is assumed to be finite dimensional?

Comment: Yeah, $V$ is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 4):

If $ETE=TE\ $ then 
$$T(E(V))=E(T(E(V)))\leqslant E(V)$$
and so $E(V)$ is $T$-invariant.

Conversely, if $E(V)$ is $T$-invariant then any $TE(x)$ is some $E(y)$, and then 
$$ETE(x)=EE(y)=E(y)=TE(x)\ \text{and so}\ ETE=TE.$$

For the rest, write $F=I-E$ and check in the usual way that $F$ is also a projection, and that moreover $\text{im} F=\ker E$ and $\text{im} E=\ker F$.

We then have (by the first part) that $\ker E=\text{im} F$ is $T$-invariant if and only if $FTF=TF$. Putting $F=1-E$ and simplifying we get that $\ker E$ is $T$-invariant if and only if $ETE=ET$.

Hence both image and kernel are $T$-invariant if and only if $TE=ET$.

Comment: how do you conclude that TE=ET while you are proving that ETE=ET ?

Comment: I don't prove or use that fact as far as I can see! All I may have left out is the straightforward fact that $ET=TE$ implies $ET=EET=ETE$ and also $ETE=TEE=TE$.

Comment: By first part, $\text{im}E$ is $T$-invariant if and only if $ETE=TE$. So $ETE=ET=TE$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Range(E) is invariant T iff ETE=TE.

Suppose ETE=TE.
Then ETE(x)=TE(x) for all x in V. Let y be in Range(E)—the Ey=y.

Now, T(y)=T(Ey)=TEy=ETE(y)=E(TEy)=E(Ty). Thus T(y) belong to Range(E). Hence the range of E is invariant under T.

Conversely, Range(E) be invariant under T and let x be in V. Then TE(x) is in the range of E, So TE(x)=E(z) for some z in V.

Now, ETE(x)=E(TEx)=E(Ez)=Ez=TE(x).

Thus ETE=TE.

2)Range of E and Null space of E are invariant under T iff TE=ET.

Suppose ET=TE and let y be in Range(E).Then Ey=y

T(y)=TEy=ETy, Thus, T(y) is in the range of E. Hence Range of E is invariant under T.
Similarly, for Null space also.

Conversely, Suppose the Null space of E say, N and the Range of E say, R are invariant under T. We know that N(E)+R(E)=V, and they are disjoint spaces. Hence, for all x in V, we can write x as r+n where r is in the range of E and n is in the null space of E.

So, x=r+n
ET(x)=ET(r+n)=ET(r)+ET(n)------(1)

Since T(r)=y is again in R and T(n)=z is again in N. Hence ET(r)=Ey=y, since y is in R. And ET(n)=Ez=0

So equation (1) will become ET(x)=ET(r)=Ey=y=T(r)

Now consider, TE(x)=TE(r+n)=TE(r)+TE(n)=T(r)+0=T(r)

Hence TE=ET

Please point out any mistakes that are there.